# Harmonic filter using numpy - smooth edges

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, wav

I am trying to write an harmonic filter.

Here is the code (Python):

```py
from scipy.io import wavfile
import numpy as np

wave_file_path = 'in.wav'
num_harmonics = 10
base_frequency = 50
sample_rate, data = wavfile.read(wave_file_path)
#  after this - sample_rate = 10,000 & len(data) = 10,000

frequencies = np.fft.fftfreq(len(data), 1.0 / sample_rate)
spectrum = np.fft.fft(data, len(data))

base_index = int(base_frequency * len(data) / sample_rate)
# the above - base_index = 50 

# Remove harmonics
for harmonics in range(2, num_harmonics + 1):
# is this the right multiply? harmonics * base_index? it maximum=500, whenever the number of spectrum elements is much bigger (10,000)
    harmonic_index = int(harmonics * base_index)
    spectrum[harmonic_index] = 0

# Inverse Fourier Transform to get filtered signal
filtered_data = np.round(np.fft.ifft(np.fft.fftshift(spectrum)).real).astype(np.int16)

output_file_path = 'out.wav'

wavfile.write(output_file_path, len(filtered_data), filtered_data)
```

Seems that this doesn't running the filter properly, since the output has not smooth edges.

Output image:

[image: output image]

The accurate solution with smooth edges should be as this:

[image: smooth image]

As I can see, the edges are not smooth for harmonic filter, and it seems that the algorithm is wrong.

Nonetheless, I check and found that `len(data)` is as same as `sample_rate`.

What may be wrong? How can I do harmonic filter based on input `wav` file?

This are some tries - I need to make the output signal (desired) as the screenshot, from the original audio signal.
[image: wave examples - input -> output]

I tried to change the parameters, check whether the base_index may be wrong.

Also, try chat-gpt and use google, but didn't find any solution for this.

Comment: I'd start by plotting `spectrum` and check it only has spikes at the fundamental (if that's what you're trying to achieve). Also in your example code at least you're not actually setting num_harmonics at all.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the code.
num_harmonic = 10 is the change.
I am trying to do "Harmonic filter", i.e. - whether the base_frequency is X=50 and num_harmonic = 10, than I should filter the frequencies of 2x50, 3x50 .... 10x50.

Comment: I also added a new screenshot for my post - input -> output.